# Word-Vba: InlineShapes.Addpicture image sits higher than its previous image

Tags: vba, ms-word

Sub GetPictures()
    Dim sPic As String
    Dim sPath As String
    Dim sCount As Long

```
sPath = "G:\Images\Alphabet_Lower_Case\"
sPic = Dir(sPath & "*.jpg")

Do While sPic <> ""

    Selection.InlineShapes.AddPicture _
      FileName:=sPath & sPic, _
      LinkToFile:=False, SaveWithDocument:=True

    With Selection
        With .Borders(wdBorderLeft)
            .LineStyle = wdLineStyleSingle
            .LineWidth = wdLineWidth300pt
            .Color = wdColorAutomatic
        End With
        With .Borders(wdBorderRight)
            .LineStyle = wdLineStyleSingle
            .LineWidth = wdLineWidth300pt
            .Color = wdColorAutomatic
        End With
        With .Borders(wdBorderTop)
            .LineStyle = wdLineStyleSingle
            .LineWidth = wdLineWidth300pt
            .Color = wdColorAutomatic
        End With
        With .Borders(wdBorderBottom)
            .LineStyle = wdLineStyleSingle
            .LineWidth = wdLineWidth300pt
            .Color = wdColorAutomatic
        End With
        .Borders.Shadow = False
    End With

    Selection.Paragraphs.Format.Alignment = wdAlignParagraphCenter

    sPic = Dir

    With Selection
    .Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseEnd
    .TypeParagraph
    End With
Loop

With ThisDocument.PageSetup.TextColumns
 .SetCount NumColumns:=2
End With

Selection.MoveRight Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=1, Extend:=wdExtend
Selection.Cut
```

End Sub

'Any idea on how to lower the image on the right hand side to the same level as the one of the left (previous)? E.g. b is sitting higher than it should be and is occluding the border.

All images have the same 600x600 dimension.
See the following output for clarification.
[a&b](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IlFfu.jpg)
Here's a screen capture and the grid behind 'b' shows the shift.
[preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wHerI.jpg)

Comment: What do you mean by lower the image on the right hand side to the same level. both looks similar to me. What you can do is decrease overall width.

Comment: You mean the "b" inside the white square? If the white square is part of the picture - so you're importing the white square with the "b", then you have to adjust it in a picture editor. There's nothing Word can do - it's not a picture editor. You need to make sure all the images are "trimmed" the same way *before* you import them.

Comment: @Eugene which version of Word are you using? I am using 2010 and I do not have the `wdLineWidth280pt` available only 225pt and 300pt